# Are there any BundleTransformer JS minifiers that support ES6?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification, bundletransformer

Are there any JS minifiers for BundleTransformer that support EcmaScript 6? I have tried installing:

- BundleTransformer.Closure
- BundleTransformer.YUI
- BundleTransformer.UglifyJs

But neither seem to handle the string template syntax of ES6, such as:

```
`Hello ${world}`
```

Am I missing something, or is it time to upgrade to Node + X?

Comment: For those of you who want to close this for being Off Topic: I would not have asked this here unless I hadn't already looked into various online resources. If you really think it is off topic, let me know why. If you don't, I will have to ask the question over again.

Answer (score 2):

Tormod!

Suppose you have the following code:

```
var world = 123;
alert(`Hello ${world}`);
```

Only two minifiers from the [Bundle Transformer](http://bundletransformer.codeplex.com/) can process it:

1. `MicrosoftAjaxJsMinifier` from [BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax/). It just minify a ES6 code.
2. `ClosureLocalJsMinifier` from [BundleTransformer.Closure](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.Closure/) with the following configuration settings:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
     …
     <bundleTransformer xmlns="http://tempuri.org/BundleTransformer.Configuration.xsd">
       …
       <closure>
         <js>
           …
           <local closureCompilerApplicationPath="…"
             javaVirtualMachinePath="…"
             languageInput="EcmaScript6" languageOutput="EcmaScript3" />
           …
         </js>
       </closure>
       …
     </bundleTransformer>
     …
   </configuration>
   ```

The transpilation from ES6 to ES3 will be made, and then the ES3 code will be minified. In addition, to the `languageOutput` attribute can be set the following values: `EcmaScript5` and `EcmaScript5Strict`.

Comment: I've tried with BundleTransformer.MicrosoftAjax and `alert('Hello ${world}`); but I'm getting these errors generated. Any tips ?
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(1,1579-1580): run-time error JS1014: Invalid character: `
(1,1586-1587): run-time error JS1193: Expected ',' or ')': $
(1,1593-1594): run-time error JS1002: Syntax error: }
(1,1594-1595): run-time error JS1014: Invalid character: `
(1,1624-1625): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: )
(1,1625-1626): run-time error JS1004: Expected ';': {
 */

Comment: @SzilardD Try installing a new module - [BundleTransformer.NUglify](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BundleTransformer.NUglify).